# Why is it said that when voltage source connected in series would only increase the voltage and not the current?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

> By adding cells in series, a larger-voltage bat-
>   tery can be made, whereas adding cells in parallel results in a battery with a higher
>   current-output capacity.

[image: And this Image]

This is what a book that I am reading says and hence what I am understanding is Voltage is added when Voltage sources are connected in series and Current s added when voltage sources are connected in parallel.

Considering the ohm's law,

1)for V1=10v and V2=10v, R = 1K, if I keep only keep V1 as voltage source, V across R would be 10v and I(current) would be 10mA.

2)Now if I connect V1 and V2 in series , V = 20V and I would be 20mA.

Did I miss something or the current actually doubled up?

I even simulated the curcuit in the Multisim and i faced with a similiar result. Any help in understanding the concept would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum limits is the key here not ohms law so....

Forget ohms law. Putting batteries in series has the maximum current limited by the weakest battery. We're talking about a single battery being able to supply x amps with two in series only able to the same maximum.

Comment: So Z1 Battery with X1(Max current) and Z2 with X2(max again!), but X2<X1. So adding Z1 and Z2 in series would give me X2? as you said "Maximum current limited by the weakest battery"

Comment: Thats what I said.

Comment: Forget about all that X1 and X2 stuff - we're talking weakest link in the chain and not some mathematical thing.

Comment: I think I confusing myself. I think theoritically I wouldn't be able to understand. Could you suggest me a practical way (like putting batteries togather or in parallel) and where to connect multimeter and what to measure for better understanding?

Comment: Measurements have nothing to do with it. If the manufacturer says 1 amp maximum and you have two batteries in series, they share the same current and that maximum current should not be greater than 1 amp. Having twice the voltage across the same resistor does double the current but this current should not exceed the maximum specified by the manufacturer.

Comment: _this current should not exceed the maximum specified by the manufacturer._ and that is supposed to be taken care by the one designing the curcuit?

Comment: Correct, you should not take currents that exceed the manufacturer's specification.

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: Apparently when i connect batteries in series, I get to use more voltage but should not abuse it by drawing more current , while when it is connected in parallel, I can draw the summation current but show not exceed the valtage.

Comment: That's the way I see it!!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that increasing voltage (putting batteries in series) would increase current across a resistor.

The batteries in series isn't adding current the way you're maybe thinking. Batteries have a max current they can deliver which you could find in a datasheet. Adding more batteries in series means they each can deliver up to their max current and the total current-output capacity increases. In parallel will also extend the life of your battery - again something like this can be found in the datasheet:
[image]

You can see if you are running your battery at a lower current it will extend battery life.